# Locating Template CSS File in Concrete5

Tags: php, css, concrete5

I just installed concrete5 and wanted to customize the css file to match the color scheme of my business.  Unfortunately, I can't find the CSS file for any of the templates.  Unlike Wordpress, it isn't simply a style.css file located inside the theme folder.  This is what the page source looks like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/concrete/index.php/tools/css/themes/solutions/main.css" />`

I get lost at index.php.  I'm not familiar enough with php to understand how a file (index.php) can have sub-folders underneath it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find it here:
YOURSITE/packages/theme_solutions/themes/solutions/main.css

BTW, the confusion is more of a concrete5 thing than a php thing -- most php programs would just load the css file from wherever it is on the server, but Concrete5 has a feature that allows end-users to modify some CSS styles, but in order to do that it runs the CSS file through its own system first and outputs it from a different location. It's an optional thing that I don't bother with when building my own sites, but many of the themes from the "marketplace" do that because they need to be more customizable for lots of different people.